# Смена языка в android приложении после публикации

Tags: java, android, google-play, context, multilanguage

После загрузки в плей маркет, языки нельзя поменять, хотя на девайсе и эмуляторе все работало исправно. Пришел к выводу что гугл блокирует языки и догружает лишь при смене системного языка, в этом ли причина? Если да, то как можно вручную их запросить, либо обойти?

А сам класс, отвечающий за это выглядит так:

```
public class MyContextWrapper extends ContextWrapper {

public MyContextWrapper(Context base) {
    super(base);
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public static ContextWrapper wrap(Context context, String language) {
    Configuration config = context.getResources().getConfiguration();
    Locale sysLocale = null;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        sysLocale = getSystemLocale(config);
    } else {
        sysLocale = getSystemLocaleLegacy(config);
    }
    if (!language.equals("") && !sysLocale.getLanguage().equals(language)) {
        Locale locale = new Locale(language);
        Locale.setDefault(locale);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            setSystemLocale(config, locale);
        } else {
            setSystemLocaleLegacy(config, locale);
        }
    }
    context.getResources().updateConfiguration(config, context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    Language.setLang(language);
    return new MyContextWrapper(context);
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public static Locale getSystemLocaleLegacy(Configuration config) {
    return config.locale;
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
public static Locale getSystemLocale(Configuration config) {
    return config.getLocales().get(0);
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public static void setSystemLocaleLegacy(Configuration config, Locale locale) {
    config.locale = locale;
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
public static void setSystemLocale(Configuration config, Locale locale) {
    config.setLocale(locale);
}

@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context newBase) {
    super.attachBaseContext(MyContextWrapper.wrap(newBase, Language.getLang()));
}
```

Comment: Да, причина в этом. Есть два решения: настроить бандл так, чтобы APK собирались со всеми (или несколькими указанными) языками, либо подгружать их принудительно. См. в ответах на en-SO: https://stackoverflow.com/q/51054175

Answer (score 5, accepted):

На этапе сборки вы можете отключить разделение языковых ресурсов в файле build.gradle:

```
android {
    bundle {
        language {
            enableSplit = false
        }
    }
}
```

Или же подгружать новый язык вручную:

```
SplitInstallRequest request = SplitInstallRequest.newBuilder()
        .addLanguage(Locale.forLanguageTag("de"))
        .build();
splitInstallManager.startInstall(request);
```

[Официальная документация](https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/configure-base#disable_config_apks).

Comment: @Эникейщик это для aab

Comment: Ааа, понял. Это инструкции для гугла, а не для АС на моем компьютере.

Answer (score 4):

У меня была подобная проблема. Я сделал все в приложение красиво и гармонично в плане смены языка, но при выгрузке его на гугл плей маркет ничего не менялось. Это для было довольно странно, так как на эмуляторе все работало правильно. Как можно увидеть из текста ситуация у меня идентичная. В чем была причина как я понял: я выгружал `android-bundle`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[Вот тут](https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle?utm_source=android-studio) можно почитать документацию про этот вариант создания инсталлера. В документации есть такой [пункт](https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle?utm_source=android-studio#known_issues):

> If you use tools that dynamically modify resource tables, APKs
> generated from app bundles might behave unexpectedly. So, when
> building an app bundle, it is recommended that you disable such tools.

То есть, если я правильно перевел, то они написали о том что грубо говоря локализация будет работать криво.

**РЕШЕНИЕ (лично у меня)**
Использовать пункт `APK` в картинке выше. Конечно гуглу такое не понравится, и при выгрузке он будет уверять вас что bundle будет лучше, что пользователю не нравится грузить тяжелые приложение. Но у меня лично приложение "увеличилось" в размере где-то на пол МБ что мне кажется не особо критично, при том что у меня около 12+ языков. Только при создании приложения учитывайте что эти две галки:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Отмечены. Ну и дальше уже собственно выгрузить не составит труда как вы понимаете :)

Comment: к сожалению поддержка apk формата будет упразднена со второй половины 2021 https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9859348?hl=ru

Comment: @Style-7, не знал)) спасибо за информацию, а ваш метод работает, а то придется что-то сочинять без апк((

Comment: я не тестировал - не было надобности, но полагаю оф док не врет